# Auto adjustable heights of containers or divisions in CSS based on browser zoom

Tags: css

I am trying to format a table using CSS but the height of each cell does not grow/shrink with the zoom level of browser. Is there any property I need to enable?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to do. The plain interpretation of the statement in the question is obviously false.

Comment: I am using microstrategy to create reports. To customize the web version of reports, I am adding CSS code that will cutomize the looks of report. Currently I am having a table in report that does not resize according to zoom. For example if the cell height in table is 24px when zoom is 100% but when I set the zoom to 150% it should readjust the height to 36px automatically, but this is not happening.

Comment: Should it? CSS `px` are not physical pixels. When you zoom in what happens is that you make the `px` unit larger.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this code doing? To elaborate on what I am doing, I am using microstrategy tool to create reports. To customize the looks of web version, I have option to add HTML containers that may contain CSS code. So to the table is already created, I look for the division names by inspecting element and then I try to change its property. So, in short I do not have any head tag. I can just add CSS code to modify the looks of content already present there. (Sorry I might sound confusing, but I do not have any idea how to explain it in better way)

Comment: @ShekharSingh well I need something to see. and you should also provide some kind of code. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
regarding the code I gave you please see this https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport